# What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?

Tags: aircraft-design

I'm considering the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow because the swallow may present an opportunity for the observation of nature to lead to better design in aviation. Many technologies built by humans are inspired by designs in nature.

If one were to set out to determine the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow, how might they go about this?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about aviation. It might be suitable for http://biology.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Further, use of the absurd term “airspeed velocity” makes this sound like a joke rather than serious question (speed and velocity are near-synonyms, with ‘speed’ usually used for the scalar and ‘velocity’ for the vector quantity).

Comment: What do you mean by measuring 'airspeed velocity' of 'unladen' swallow? Speed is a scalar and velocity is a vector; I don't think anyone uses different methods for measuring speeds of laden and unladen birds.

Comment: @JanHudec `makes this sound like a joke` I have to infer then that you have never heard of Monty Python

Comment: @Federico, of course I did. That's just more reason to think it is a joke (along with similarly silly “unladen swallow” as if swallows usually carried burdens).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a joke.

Comment: This guy did put some serious though into it though. http://style.org/unladenswallow/

Comment: For curiosity: What is a *laden* or *unladen* bird, my bilingual dictionary isn't helpful in this context :(

Comment: These two videos should provide some context.
http://youtu.be/liIlW-ovx0Y
http://youtu.be/_7iXw9zZrLo

Comment: @mins *lade* is a verb and a synonym of *load*. So *laden* means carrying a load or burden.

Comment: You guys are killing me with the down votes! This is such a good question. Haters.

Comment: If this weren't off-topic, we would still need to know your favorite color and the capital of Assyria before we could proceed with a useful answer.

Comment: Wait. What? I don't know that. Ahhhhhh!!!

Comment: @RyanBurnette: Thank you for such enlightenment. The question should be *migrated*. Thanks TomMcW too.

Comment: @RyanBurnette if you hadn't already asked this I was going to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the method of getting the airspeed of any bird is pretty much the same:

- Measure the ground speed of the bird.
- Measure the wind speed in the area.
- Calculate the airspeed of the bird from these two values.

The following excerpt from [*Air speeds of migrating birds observed by ornithodolite and compared with predictions from flight theory*](http://rsif.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/10/86/20130419) by C. J. Pennycuick et al. published by the Royal Society details one such method:

> We measured the bird's air speed, for comparison with the predictions of theory, in two stages. First, we measured the ground speed vector, consisting of the bird's speed relative to the observer's position on the shore and its track direction, i.e. the direction in which the bird was moving over the ground, measured clockwise from true north. We also measured the wind vector consisting of the wind speed and the direction from which the wind was blowing, and then obtained the air speed vector (air speed and heading direction) by vector subtraction of the wind vector from the ground speed vector

Other researchers have used  Doppler radar for the same purpose and in case of high flying birds, one can simply fly along with the birds at the same speed and measure the airspeed.

Comment: You didn't ask if we're talking African or European.

Comment: Assumptions must be made because your question is incomplete.  Be more specific next time.